Extracting segment of specified length from line geometry using pointgeometry as middlepoint (not as geometry centerpoint) with Python
I have a line and point geoemtry. I need to extract segments of the line geoemtry based on the point geometry. The point geometry contains the length of the segment I need to 'cut' as an attribute value and it is the middlepoint (not the geoemtric centerpoint) of the to-be-extracted line segment.
I have attached an image. The yellow marked part of the geoemtry I need to extract from the line, using the point geometry which marks the middlepoint of the length of the to-be-extracted line segment.

I first thought to use a buffer around the middlepoint, but this is not exact enought.
Is there a way to do this with Python (e.g. GeoPandas)?

points along line might suffice, once you know, how far down the line your point is.

Hi @Erik Thank your for answering! I'm not quite sure if I understand your answer. I need to extract a segment from a line geoemtrey, or in other words, I need to 'cut it out', based on a point I have, which should mark the middlepoint of the line-segment.

You have a point, you know how far down the line it is, you know the length of the segment you want to extract - so you know everything you need to use points along line, giving you the starting and end point of your extract, allowing your to extract the actual geometry.

@Erik This is the method I also use, but it is more like a work around, and it needs quite a few steps. It would be nice if there would be a tool, with which you could set the distance from a certain point on a line and create point geometries, instead of creating a lot of redundant points. Still thank you for your help!

You can use shapely .project

Returns the distance along this geometry to a point nearest the
specified point

to find the points distance along the geometry.
.interpolate

Return a point at the specified distance along a linear geometry

to create two points where the line segment should start and end.
and shapely.ops.split

Splits a geometry by another geometry and returns a collection of
geometries

to split the line at the two points.
(GeoPandas is just for plotting)
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

linedf = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/oneroad.shp")
pointdf = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/onepoint.shp")

#Extract the geometries
linegeom = linedf.iloc[0].geometry
pointgeom = pointdf.iloc[0].geometry
print(type(linegeom))
#<class 'shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString'> They are shapely geometries

#At what distance along the line is the point geometry?
centerdistance = linegeom.project(pointgeom)
print(centerdistance)
#490.48800586225224

#Create two points where the line should start and end
segmentlength = 200 #The total length of the line to extract
pnt1 = linegeom.interpolate(centerdistance-segmentlength/2) #Create a start point
pnt2 = linegeom.interpolate(centerdistance+segmentlength/2) #And end point
splitters = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[pnt1, pnt2], crs=linedf.crs) #And a df just for plotting

#Plot
ax = linedf.plot(figsize=(10,15), linewidth=1, color="black", zorder=1)
pointdf.plot(ax=ax, color="blue", zorder=2)
splitters.plot(ax=ax, color="red", zorder=2)


It should work to split the line using the points, but it doesnt. Even if I snap the points to the line.
So I clip a short segment of the line at the two red points and rotate them 90 degrees and use to split the original line:
cutline1 = shapely.affinity.rotate(geom=pnt1.buffer(0.1).intersection(linegeom), 
                                   angle=90, origin="center")
cutline2 = shapely.affinity.rotate(geom=pnt2.buffer(0.1).intersection(linegeom), 
                                   angle=90, origin="center")

split_linegeoms = list(shapely.ops.split(geom=linegeom, splitter=shapely.MultiLineString([cutline1, cutline2])).geoms)
split_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=split_linegeoms, crs=linedf.crs)

split_df.plot(ax=ax, color=["lime", "yellow", "magenta"], linestyle="--")


the_mid_segment = split_linegeoms[1]



Thank you @BERA! I will try this out!

I just wanted to thank you, @BERA! It did help me!
